# .editorconfig JetBrains value with space

Tags: ide, webstorm, jetbrains-ide, editorconfig

I created **Code Style** rules for my HTML files in JetBrains editor.

One of my rule is:

[image]

then I export my rules to *.editorconfig* file:

[image]

when I open my file I see one error for that rule:

[image]

also when I reformat code it will break into multiple lines

[image]

How to setup editor to not showing error and not breaking rule into multiple lines? I didn't find any rule in EditorConfig Code Style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a known issue.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-244480 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified with any progress.